# How to pass the unique pointer to specific param required in function?

Tags: c++

A short yet effective example below:

```
std::unique_ptr<float> x(new float[whatever_size]);
```

I have a function with prototype:

```
void function(float*&);
```

How can I go about calling it by passing in the x.
I tried:

```
function(x.get()); // complains no argument matches float*&
function(&x.get()); // complains requires lvalue.
```

A short answer with an explanation would be great. 
 Thanks!

Comment: You should use `std::unique_ptr<float[]>` for an array (or better use a vector).

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate problem, but your `x` should be declared as `std::unique_ptr<float[]>` - otherwise your code would exhibit undefined behavior due to an array being deleted with `delete` instead of `delete[]`.

Comment: Why does `function` take in a `float*&` instead of `float*`? Does it actually modify its argument, and if so what does it do?

Comment: @DanielH it does modify its argument.

Comment: You really don't want to do any of this.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI In what way does it modify its argument? Does it allocate something new and make `f` point to that instead? Does it make it point to some other pre-existing `float` or array of `float`s? Does it do anything with the old value, like `delete` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, you should know that a unique pointer doesn't magically protect you from messing up memory management. Your use case is extremely fishy, and I would caution you to not assume a unique pointer will solve everything and anything.

---

`function` expects a modifiable lvalue reference. The call `x.get()` returns an rvalue. Naturally the reference won't bind to it, no matter how hard you try. Now, the obvious solution is to introduce a temporary:

```
auto *f = x.get();
function(f);
```

But that may come back and shoot you in the foot if `function` needs to actually modify `f`, the pointer and not the pointee.

---

Since you mentioned it a comment that it indeed modifies its argument. You must reliniquish ownership from the unique pointer before the call, and give it back after:

```
auto *f = x.release();
function(f);
x.reset(f);
```

That is the only way the change will reflect in `x`. But again, it's still a bit fragile.

Comment: The `release`-and-`reset` sequence might or might not work correctly, depending on what exactly `function` does. For example, you might want to skip the `release` step if `function` doesn’t deallocate `f`.

Comment: @DanielH If the function doesn't modify the passed in pointer then why does it receive it by non-const reference?

Comment: @DanielH - The release does no harm if `function` is civilized. If it accepts a raw pointer that it should own for the call, and throws without deallocating, it's evil and should not be used.

Comment: @Galik It modifies it, but that doesn’t mean it’s going to deallocate it. It might assume there’s another copy of the passed-in pointer somewhere which will be `delete`d.

Comment: The function does modify the passed pointer. Why would it get deallocated when it is a unique_ptr?

Comment: @StoryTeller I’m thinking about if `function` doesn’t deallocate, and isn’t supposed to deallocate, and just uses an in-out parameter for some reason.

Comment: That’s why I asked for details about the modification. They matter for ownership, which matters for how to handle the call.

Comment: @DanielH - Then like I said, `release` is just a couple of wasted instructions. I'd rather have them there myself, than not.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI -  A unique pointer doesn't magically protect you from messing up memory management. Your use case is extremely fishy, and I would caution you to not assume a unique pointer will solve everything and anything.

Comment: @StoryTeller Suppose `function` is `findFirstZero`, and sets `f` to the first element in the passed-in array which which is equal to zero. Then it doesn’t deallocate `f`, and isn’t supposed to, and releasing/resetting is completely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: There is no possible modification of a pointer that won't break ownership

Comment: What is the equivalent of this to using unique_ptr... float* x = new float[size]; Why do I need the [] when doing the unique_ptr..?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI It tells the `unique_ptr` whether or not to provide `operator[]`, and whether to delete with `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: @DanielH so why can't I just use it without the [] in my case?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Because, even if you don’t want to use the subscripting operator, it’s undefined behavior to use `delete` instead of `delete[]` when you allocate with `new[]`. It might be that in your implementation it works for types with trivial destructors, but it might also be that it *appears to* work but causes subtle problems later, and either way that can change if you use a different compiler or different compiler flags.

Comment: It amazes me why we can't do &x.get()

Comment: @OmidCompSCI - Program a few years in C++. It will cease to amaze you. In fact you'll become grateful for it.

Comment: If `function()` really needs to deallocate `f` and allocate a new array for output, I would probably use something more like this: `auto *f = x.get(); function(f); if (x.get() != f) { x.release(); x.reset(f); }` This way, the `unique_ptr` releases ownership and reacquires it only if a new allocation actually occurs, and maintains ownership if no allocation occurs, or an exception is thrown prior to allocation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the function can modify the pointer you pass to it (passed by non-const reference), potentially re-seating it. If that is the case, then you would have to do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> x(new float[N]); // remember the array type []

float* fp = x.release();
func(fp);
x.reset(fp);
```

But the critical point is passing in a proper (named) pointer, not just a temporary pointer returned by `x.get()`.

Your error occurs because the function is unable to modify the temporary pointer returned by the function `x.get()`. You have to give it a **real** pointer that can change value.